# Bootstrap paginator div not positioning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, positioning

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.4 to achieve the following page layout:

- header: fixed to top ;
- top content row: fixed below page header ;
- main content row: contains scrollable data ;
- pagination links row: fixed, should show above footer ;
- footer: fixed to bottom ;

  I have it set up except for the pagination row. I have tried and tried but I just don't see what is going on. The problem is that the pagination row doesn't show beneath the main content area, as I expect it to. It shows near the top of the page.

The only way I managed to position it where it should be is by inserting a `margin-top: 537px;` but this doesn't adjust with the rest of the content when I resize the window.

(I have left the top content row to do once I have sorted this problem out)

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.body-content {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  bottom: 12%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- nav button -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- nav branding link -->
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">site branding</a>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Learn <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Tutorials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Java</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Python</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Scala</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Code samples</li>
            <li><a href="#">Java</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Python</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Scala</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="pbb-content1" class="container-fluid body-content panel-group">
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
  <p>sdofjsdnvkvn</p>
</div>
<!-- end pbb-content1 -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #FF9999">left</div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color: #FF8888">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&lt;</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/1" class="active">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/3">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/4">4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/5">5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/6">6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/7">7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/8">8</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/9">9</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/10">10</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/11">11</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/2">&gt;</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/myserverurl/119">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #FF6666">right</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pbb-footer" class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: grey;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p style="text-align: center;">This is the footer : wekdmtryoslcxkm4l534l5klkmdclvwperr987</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas as to how I can make the pagination appear after the main content?

Answer (score 0):

```
.body-content {
background-color: grey;    
top: 22%;
bottom: 12%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

If you want make the pagination appear after the main content remove this line `position: absolute;`

Make your content body scroll:

```
#pbb-content1{
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does place the pagination after the main content but it also makes the whole page scrollable... including the header and footer. I want those to be fixed with only the content in the middle area of the page to be scrollable.